# How can we tell the exact time a bounty will expire?

Tags: discussion, bounty, bug-reporting-process

I can see a bounty will expire 'tomorrow'. That could mean a bunch of different things depending on timezones, start of day vs end of day etc.

How can we see the time (not just the day) that a bounty will expire?

Edit: different site users seem to see different things - possibly related to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337013/new-post-notices-rollout-on-stack-overflow) bug (see Tom's comment below) - but possibly intentional (through A/B testing). Some users need to hover over 'tomorrow', whereas other users need to hover over the '+100' to see the bounty end time.

Comment: Hover your mouse over the word "tomorrow" and it shows exact start and end times.  So tomorrow at 17:19:52 UTC.

Comment: @HansPassant sounds reasonable, but doesn't seem to work. (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58805740/using-r-to-download-data-automatically))

Comment: works for me, a tooltip appears after a second

Comment: @Gimby Because you checked on the old notification. The new, blue one doesn't work.

Comment: @Tom I don't really understand why it's different for different site users?

Comment: @user5783745 That's how testing a feature works, you roll it out to a certain, random, group of people to test it before releasing it for all.

Comment: @Tom oh so it's A/B testing sorta thing?

Comment: I've created a bug report there https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337013/new-post-notices-rollout-on-stack-overflow/338671#338671 ... let's see if they fix it.

Comment: The issue is fixed: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338671/273397

Comment: @Tom nice work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hovering over the "tomorrow" will show you a tooltip that lists the bounty's start and end times:

> [image]

Comment: I checked the page html. For me, for some reason, hovering over tomorrow does nothing, but hovering over the '+100' displays the tool tip with the ending date. (discovered it in the page html)

Comment: The "tomorrow" does have a `title` attribute in the HTML, though.

Comment: Check out Tom's comment above, he thinks we are seeing different things

Comment: Oh, that makes sense... It could've been overlooked in the update.